# ISPConfig, Testing website without domain name

Tags: ispconfig

I have a VPS with ISPConfig 3. I just create a website and ftp access.How can I test my website without domain name ?

Comment: via the servers IP address?

Comment: yes @fanlim plz

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your local `/etc/hosts` to match your VPS IP & domain.

```
x.x.x.x   domain.tld
```

Where x.x.x.x should be replaced by your VPS IP address.

Save the file and hit your domain.tld in the address bar.